# Why does the function not return a value?

Tags: python

Can you please take a look at the function `chooseSampleKey` and help me understand why it does not always return a value? It returns a value sometimes, and at other times returns None, so you will have to run it a few times. The problem is especially in the branch that I have named problem branch. It seems to me that the code should always return a value, but either I am going wrong somewhere or there is a bug in Python.

```
import random

peeps = {1: [], 2: [], 3: ['A', 'B'], 4: ['C', 'D'], 5: ['E']}

dictkeys = [1, 2, 4, 5]

def chooseSampleKey(peeps, dictkeys):
    if len(dictkeys) > 0:
        sampleKey = random.sample(dictkeys, 1)[0]
        print 'From chooseSampleKey, sampleKey = ', sampleKey
        print "peeps in samplekey: ", len( peeps[sampleKey] )

        if len( peeps[sampleKey] ) > 0:

            # **problem branch**: sampleKey is defined and has a value.
            # the function comes here and prints the following statement
            # with the value of samplekey. However, despite printing 
            # a value for sampleKey in following line, 
            # the print for the function itself prints None, i.e., no 
            # value is returned.

            print "Returning samplekey {0}".format( sampleKey )
            return sampleKey

        else:
            dictkeys.remove(sampleKey)
            chooseSampleKey(peeps, dictkeys)
    else:
        return 0


print chooseSampleKey(peepsTemp, [1, 2, 4, 5])
```

Please run the code a few times and you will see the problem described.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't in the first `else:` clause, where there is no `return` statement? If you want recursion, you'll want to do `return chooseSampleKey(peeps, dictkeys)`.

Comment: We don't need to run the code. It's right there in the code in the branch that doesn't return a value.

Comment: I agree there is no return statement in the first else. But I don' t understand the following: the function prints, say "Returning sample key 5", which tells me it has reached the problem branch. In that branch there is a return statement . . . so once it is in that branch it should return a value. But it instead returns None. Why does it even go to the else part?

Comment: @Curious2learn your function is also recursive (it calls itself) so the fact that it returns a value in that branch doesn't mean that the function, as a whole, returns a value. All that matters is what it returns at the initial call to `chooseSampleKey`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not returning a value here:

```
    else:
        dictkeys.remove(sampleKey)
        chooseSampleKey(peeps, dictkeys)
        # here <-----------
else:
    return 0
```

You need to ensure that all paths through your function end at a return statement.

Otherwise Python will return `None` which is the default return value for all functions (i.e., when no return statement has been written).

Comment: Can you please see my comment in above? The return is None even when the code enters the "problem branch". Once it enters that branch should it not return with value of sampleKey since there is a return in that branch?

Comment: @Curious2learn see above, what matters is what you return at the initial call to `chooseSampleKey`, not what you return at intermediate function calls.